# Issue with my slide toggling (sorry for vague title)

Tags: jquery, html

Hello sorry for the vague title but I couldn't think of a title.

I have written the following code. You do not need to read it completely just read my error below all the code.

HTML:

```
<!-- 1 -->
<div class="title">
    <p>title</p>
</div>

<div class="boxes">
    <div class="box">boxes1</div>
    <div class="box">boxes1</div>
</div>

<!-- 2 -->
<div class="title">
    <p>title</p>
</div>

<div class="boxes">
    <div class="box">boxes2</div>
    <div class="box">boxes2</div>
</div>

<!-- 3 -->
<div class="title">
    <p>title</p>
</div>

<div class="boxes">
    <div class="box">boxes3</div>
    <div class="box">boxes3</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(".title").click(function(){
   jQuery(".boxes").slideUp();
   jQuery(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

CSS:

```
.boxes {
  display: none;
}
```

What it does is when the 'title' div is clicked, the 'boxes' div immediately following it gets opened.

Also it closes any other 'boxes' div that is open.

It all works fine but the issue is that when a 'boxes' div is open and you attempt to close it by clicking the 'title' div immediately above it, that boxes div will close then open again.

Anyone know how to rewrite this code to fix this glitch?

Ive provided a jsfiddle link below to recreate the error. To recreate the error click on 'title' then click it again to close it. You will see the glitch I am talking about

[jsfiddle-link](http://jsfiddle.net/h4JXs/5154/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made my own changes to your [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/h4JXs/5157/). What I changed:

- store the state of their toggle in a variable called `open`
- gave each of the titles a unique id property
- when a title is clicked, I call `toggleVisibility` which stores the original state of the clicked title, negates all of their states, and then sets the clicked title's toggle state to the inverse of its original state.
- once the state is updated, the new state of the clicked title is checked and that box will be opened if `true`.